# Pandas: Value_counts() function explanation

Tags: pandas

I wanted to ask if anyone knows if its possible to return a single value using the value_counts() in pandas or if there is a possible way to isolate a single value?

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by return a single value? Maybe you are looking for [`.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to 'a possible way to isolate a single value' question:

[iat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) accesses a single value:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series([f"value_{x}" for x in range(20)])

data.iat[4]
```

Combining this with `value_counts()` method:

```
import pandas as pd

numbers = [f"value_{x}" for x in range(20)]
numbers[5] = numbers[6]

data = pd.Series(numbers)

data.value_counts().iat[0]
```

Comment: Did this suggestion help? Thanks :)